# minimal trading amount per transaction, looking for exchange

Tags: cryptocurrency

I currently developed crypto bot with support of low transaction estimate to buy/sell. Now I am looking for exchange allowing to buy all possible pairs for under a \$1 or even less. Let's say BTC/USDT and I will be able to buy BTC for $1 or less. With same example follow for all pairs.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptographys.SE. If you read our [help/on-topic] you will see that Cryptography.SE is only related to the Cryptography side of Cryptocurrencies. This question about the transaction estimate is about economics, therefore off-topic here. See also; [Community-specific reason for closing cryptocurrency questions?](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1500/18298)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for a cryptocurrency exchange recommendation and not about cryptography itself.

Comment: ok fine, I am sorry about this. Agree to close it